# image disappear instead of showing in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, hover, opacity

I'm using CSS hover and opacity to make one image change into another when you hover over it, By placing one on top and setting the opacity so that it disappears on hover and the bottom image is left. Code is as follows:

```
#fade {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;


}
#fade img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }



#fade img.topfade:hover {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=5)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=.5);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

}
```

This works fine in ie8,ie9 and firefox but in ie7 the second image is not there when the first image is made invisible. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: my answer wasn't good, so I've deleted it. I've been trying to work with your CSS in jsfiddle -- see http://jsfiddle.net/8HLdx/ -- but I guess I also needed to see your HTML code. Feel free to play with the example in JSFiddle; it's a great little playground for testing JS and CSS code. I'm not seeing any opacity in the test in either IE7 or IE8, but as I say, I had to guess your HTML structure.

Comment: the opacity is just used to make the first image disappear to reveal the one behind it. The html is: <div class="moveable"><li> <div class="fade"><a href="#"><img class="bottom" src="images/pic.jpg" /><img class="topfade" src="images/pic.jpg" /></a></div></li></div>

Answer (score 1):

I have [made a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6CZTz/3/) which seems to work for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE7.

It works in IE8+ as the `-ms-filter` rule is correct, however opacity in IE7 is the `filter:alpha(opacity=xx)` rule and the value should be [between 0 and 100](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your current value `.5` is making the hovered image almost totally opaque (and I'm not sure it's even valid).

[quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) has a good summary of the different opacity CSS rules for IE.

Note: In your example structure you are missing a `<ul>` or `<ol>` before the `<li>` which I have added in the demo.